# Fastlane git commits from current branch added in app build

Tags: git, fastlane

Is there a way to add all git commits only from the current branch in the build that will be created?

I create a build every time I finish the work from a current branch and I want the changelog to have only the commits made in my current branch.

I tried using ***number_of_commits*** and used it in ***commits_count*** in ***changelog_from_git_commits*** method like this :

```
  lane :test do
    changelog = changelog_from_git_commits(
        commits_count: number_of_commits, 
        pretty: "- %s", 
        date_format: "short",
        match_lightweight_tag: false, 
        merge_commit_filtering: "exclude_merges"
    )
    build_app(scheme: "test")
    upload_to_testflight(
      changelog: changelog
    )
  end
```

Also ar first i used ***between*** but it gives me all commits from the last tag:

```
 lane :test do
        changelog = changelog_from_git_commits(
        between: [last_git_tag, "HEAD"],
        pretty: "- %s",
        date_format: "short",
        match_lightweight_tag: false,
        merge_commit_filtering: "exclude_merges"
    )
    build_app(scheme: "test")
    upload_to_testflight(
      changelog: changelog
    )
  end
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: You can read more flags here https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats and run something like `fastlane run changelog_from_git_commits merge_commit_filtering:"exclude_merges" pretty:"%d - %s" quiet: | grep origin/test`

Comment: also check the tests for some ideas https://github.com/HonzaMac/fastlane/blob/fcd41e86a1a9883e917997f43411d1dec4969021/fastlane/spec/actions_specs/changelog_from_git_commits_spec.rb

Answer (score 5):

The most accurate way to do this is by doing a comparison against `origin/master` I made it work by doing this:

```
changelog_from_git_commits(
  merge_commit_filtering: "exclude_merges",
  between: ["origin/master", "HEAD"]
)
```